# How can we use async/await inside describe?

Tags: typescript, karma-jasmine, e2e-testing

I have been trying to execute the below end-to-end test for my project.
I have an array of pages. Each includes a page name and list of steps involved.
But to get those pages, I need to make an async call. Due to that, 'it' method is not getting executed.

I need to iterate the 'it' method for all my pages.

```
describe('Test Suite', () => {
    let pages: Page[]; //Page = { Name: string, testSteps: string[] } 
    beforeAll(async () => {
        pages = await service.GetPages();
    });
    pages.forEach((page) => {
        it("Test Cases", () => {
            return executePageTests(page);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: How about `describe('Test Suite', async () => { let pages = await service.GetPages(); pages.forEach((page) => {
        it("Test Cases", () => { ...  }) ...`

Comment: I have tried the same but that is not working. Please go through this [link](https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine/issues/1487)

Answer (score 0):

Jasmine doesn't support Promises directly. It does support [asynchronous callbacks via a `done` function](https://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-Asynchronous_Support) but only for `beforeEach`, `it`, and `afterEach`, not `describe`. In other words, you cannot make an asynchronous call to generate test cases, and this makes sense really because you want test discovery to be fast.

The best you can hope for is to have one test that executes all test cases.

```
   it("Test all cases", done => { 
     service.GetPages().then(pages => { 
        pages.forEach(executePageTest);
        done();
     });
   })
```